# Showing and editing has_many objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do something that I imagine to be very basic, but I'm very new to Rails and am not sure what sure what I'm doing wrong. I've gone through several tutorials and searched for an answer and can't find what the issue is. Would appreciate any help!

I've got Models set up so that Clients have many Projects which have many Milestones:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :milestones, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Milestone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Routes are set up as follows:

```
 resources :clients
 resources :milestones
 resources :projects do
   resources :milestones
 end
```

In projects/show.html.erb, I want to display each milestone associated with a project and also provide a form that adds new milestones on that same page. When I submit the form, it adds a new milestone (a new LI within UL.card-list), but none of the values show up. Here is the code for projects/show.html.erb:

```
  <h2><%= @project.name %> Milestones</h2>

  <ul class="card-list">
    <% @project.milestones.each do |m| %>
    <li>
      <div class="card-header">
        <%= m.date %>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="name"><%= m.name %></h3>
        <p class="description"><%= m.description %></p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <% end %>
    <li>
      <div class="card-header">
        New Milestone
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <%= form_for [@project,Milestone.new] do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field(:project_id, value: @project.id) %>         
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :milestone %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :description %>
            <%= f.text_area :description %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :date %>
            <%= f.date_field :date %>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Add Milestone" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>        
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Here are the parameters that are coming through the form:

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"3D12GTH+IhwMMQDKsj2l+KXe7OBxmub3eejb3pbpWao=", 
  "milestone"=>{
    "project_id"=>"1", 
    "name"=>"Test Milestone", 
    "description"=>"test descrip", 
    "date"=>"2015-06-26"
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Add Milestone", 
  "project_id"=>"1"
}
```

Milestones controller:

```
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @milestone = @project.milestones.create!(params[milestone_params])
    redirect_to @project
  end

  private
  def milestone_params
    params.require(:milestone).permit(:name, :description, :completed, :date, :project_id)
  end
```

Please let me know if there's any other info I can provide that would help. Thanks!

Comment: "I want to display each milestone associated with a project and also provide a form that adds new projects on that same page." Do you mean "adds new milestones"?

Comment: Correct, adds new milestones. Thanks, Maxcal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to support both (`POST /milestones` and `POST /projects/:project_id/milestones`) the `project_id` to the form:

```
<%= form_for [@project,Milestone.new] do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.hidden_field(:project_id, value: @project_id) %> 
  ...
<%- end -%>
```

Or if your resource is always nested than `project_id` available in the params in your controller so you can just pass it:

```
class MilestonesContoller < ApplicationController
  def create
    @milestone = Milestone.new(milestone_params)
    # this part was originally omitted for brevity.
    if @milestone.save
      redirect_to @milestone.project
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # don't trust params from the scary interwebs
  def milestone_params
    params.require(:milestone)
          .permit(:project_id, :name, :description, :date)
  end
end
```

**NOTE** that you actually need to integrate this code with the other actions in your controller. It is just a minimal example to show the relevant concepts. Not something which is meant as a complete copy-paste-done solution.

You can also reduce your routes file down to:

```
resources :clients
resources :milestones
resources :projects do
  resources :milestones
end
```

Use the [options for `resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) if you need to customize the routes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the routes file, maxcal! Unfortunately, I'm still seeing the same issue with Milestone values not appearing. I updated the question and added what I have in my controller in case that helps.

If I replace this:

`@milestone = @project.milestones.create!(params[milestone_params])`

with this:

`@milestone = Milestone.new(milestone_params)`
then it no longer even updates the number of milestones when I submit the form. Any ideas?

Comment: I omitted the rest of the create method for brevity. A `#...` comment usually means that the author has left out parts of the code and that you are required do some assembly yourself. I have edited the question and added the missing pieces.

Comment: That was it. Thanks, maxcal! Much appreciated!